# Throttle access to resource

Tags: c#, multithreading, throttling

I'm wondering how to implement a wrapper for a REST service that needs throttling. The service is rate limited to e.g. "Max 60 calls per minute" or similar. Overusing the resource means my client is blocked for an extended time so I must take care to not let that happen, thus I'd like the wrapper itself to be rate limited.

Edit: removed final idea and posted it as the answer

Comment: Well, "Max 60 calls per minute"  clearly means you need to be able to tell the number of requests you've made in the last minute (at least) and check that. So just store a list of the `DateTime` you've made requests. Then, on every new request, check how many you've made in the last minute and discard any older information, since you don't need it any more.

Comment: I think you shouldn't just wait around and I find the solution @Alex proposed better, you should definitely count the requests done in the last minute. What's ugly about a single thread managing others?

Comment: @Alex yes, storing a list of requests will let me make the change from "minimum interval between requests" to the better one "Max requests per timespan". What do I do when there are too many requests made in the last period though? Just wait? Also I'm worried the collection of recent requests may be a source of contention (for large numbers of requests and/or long timeperiods. If the req limit is 100k/hour there is a lot of counting to do (and other threads will be locked out meanwhile).

Comment: @AndersForsgren Then you could group the requests by minute (or some other appropriate amount of time). You'll have a list of about 60 tuples `<minite, requests count>` and just increment the request count for the current minute when a new request can be processed. Essentially on heavy load you will be processing the request minute by minute but you'll have less processing to do on the request list. As for what to do when the requests fill up - you can let the threads race for taking the free spot in a synchronized block, or build up a queue, or throw an exception if you have to wait too long.

Comment: @Alex I have updated my solution to incorporate keeping the request times as it solves the problem better than the previous examples. I'll accept yours as the answer (if you want to post an answer), otherwise I'll move my example snippet to an answer and accept my own answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your snippet _is_ the answer, I'm glad I could help you get to it. I think you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, inspired by the comment by @Alex, this one solves the problem of max N requests in time span T. It holds the times of the last N requests in a list (cyclic buffer) and allows the request if the oldest call was older than T.

```
public class Throttler<T>
{
   private readonly long[] callTimes;
   private int cur;      
   private readonly Func<T> func;
   private readonly TimeSpan interval;
   private readonly object padlock = new object();    

   public Throttler(Func<T> func, int maxCalls, TimeSpan interval)
   {
      this.func = func;
      callTimes = new long[maxCalls];
      this.interval = interval;
      cur = 0;
   }

   public T Call()
   {
      lock (padlock)
      {
         do
         {
            long oldestCall = callTimes[(cur + 1)%callTimes.Length];
            long now = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;               
            if (now - oldestCall > interval.Ticks)
            {                 
               cur = (cur + 1) % callTimes.Length;                  
               callTimes[cur] = now;
               return func();
            }
            int sleepTime = (int)((interval.Ticks - (now - oldestCall))/TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) + 1;               
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);               
         } while (true);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can speed up the requests if you move the actual invocation of `func` outside the synchronized block (`break` out of the loop instead of returning and move `return func()` after the closing bracket of `lock`) :)